# Count number of email sent to a person

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to get the number of times that a person has been sent an email, so I can keep track of leads, for example

```
user@domain.com was emailed 5 times
user2@domain.com was emailed 3 times
```

From reading the docs I cannot figure this one out

Is this possible?

EDIT:

```
 function myFunction(e) {

  e = "someemail@gmail.com";
  var threads = GmailApp.search("to:" + e + "");
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
       count++;     
   }
   Logger.log(count) //1
}
```

This gives me threads but no number of messages

Comment: Take a look at the [GMailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) and put together some code you post up so the question is a bit more specifc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right lines using search() to find the sent items. This is a snippet I use to scan through all the unread emails in the inbox, and the processing that email. You'll want something similar:

```
  var totalThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads().length
  // Read in READ_AT_ONCE pages of email at a time
  for (var pageindex = 0; pageindex < totalThreads; pageindex += READ_AT_ONCE) {
    var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(pageindex, READ_AT_ONCE)
    var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads)
    var numThreads = threads.length
    // Read in all the threads in the batch
    for (var threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < numThreads; threadIndex++) {
      var numMsgs = msgs[threadIndex].length         
      // Process each msg in the thread
      for (var msgIndex = 0; msgIndex < numMsgs; msgIndex++) {
        var msg = msgs[threadIndex][msgIndex]
        if (!msg.isUnread() || msg.isInTrash()) {
          continue
        }
        Email_.processMsg(msg)    
      } // for each msg
    } // for each thread        
  } // for each batch
```